# Spark RandomForest training StackOverflow error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, random-forest, apache-spark-ml

I am running a training of my model and I am getting the StackOverflow error whenever I increase the maxDepth over 12. 
Everything works correctly for 5,10,11.

I am using spark 2.0.2 (and i cannot upgrade it for next couple of weeks). 
I have > 3M data, 200 features, 2500 trees and I would like to improve the accuracy by increasing the max depth. Is there a way to overcome this problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 92 in stage 789.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 92.3 in stage 789.0 (TID 66903, 10.0.0.11): java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHandle(ObjectInputStream.java:1643)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2122)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2122)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2122)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: maybe your memory is not big enough

Comment: @Wang os memory was fine, the stack wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like specifying the spark-submit option:

```
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xss8m --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss8m
```

does the job.

This can also be configured in the conf/spark-env.sh on each node, more about that:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html